"Deprecated: This package has been deprecated" Warning When Installing Widely Used Nuget Packages
I am trying to install several Nuget packages, but Nuget labels them as "Deprecated". However, I know for a fact that they are still widely used and included in other "Non-Deprecated" packages. For example, see latest versions of following packages:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies

Please note that all of the packages are labeled as "Deprecated", even though they are relied on and included in other non-deprecated nuget packages.
Here are my three questions:

Is there a way to find out which other packages depend on the deprecated package I need? That way, I can install a non-deprecated parent package and the needed package is automatically added too. However, this seems to be a very convoluted way to get a needed package.
Are there concerns that I need to be aware of if it becomes necessary to install a deprecated package?
There must be something I am completely missing. This seems like a round-about way to address something that should be simple. Is there another (potentially much better) way to do what I need to do?


Did you faced any issue when using the deprecated packages? Deprecated doesn't mean the package can't be used any more, we can still use them. In nuget website, we can see This package has been deprecated as it is legacy and is no longer maintained. for the deprecated package description. We can still use them but they might have some bugs which won't be fixed any more, and might have compatibility issues with some latest feature/libraries. We might have a replacement with some other new packages for the deprecated ones, but it depends on your requirement to choose the packages.

I believe all of those packages are now available in ASP.NET Core and don't need to be separately installed.

Very well announced https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/217 but you will have to read further to know more details.
